# ArrayOfAnyType issues when calling the method:GetRangeA1 excel web services in the silverlight 4.0

Tags: web-services, excel, silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I create a simple silverlight 4.0 application used to read the excel file data in the share point 2010 server. I try to use the "Excel Web Services" but I get an error here when calling the GetRangeA1 method:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/server/webservices:GetRangeA1Response. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 361. Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/server/webservices:anyType' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/server/webservices:ArrayOfAnyType'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to 'ArrayOfAnyType' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

the source code is like:

```
namespace SampleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExcelServiceSoapClient xlservice = new ExcelServiceSoapClient();
            xlservice.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            Status[] outStatus;

            string targetWorkbookPath = "http://phc/Shared%20Documents/sample.xlsx";

            try
            {
                // Call open workbook, and point to the trusted location of the workbook to open.
                string sessionId = xlservice.OpenWorkbook(targetWorkbookPath, "en-US", "en-US", out outStatus);
                Console.WriteLine("sessionID : {0}", sessionId);

                //1. works fines.
                object res = xlservice.GetCellA1(sessionId, "CER by Feature", "B1", true, out outStatus); 

                //2. exception
                xlservice.GetRangeA1(sessionId, "CER by Feature", "H19:H21", true, out outStatus);

                // Close workbook. This also closes session.
                xlservice.CloseWorkbook(sessionId);
            }
            catch (SoapException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SOAP Exception Message: {0}", e.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am totally new to the silverlight and sharepoint developping, I search around but didn't get any luck, just found another post [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/ab2a08d5-2e91-4dc1-bd80-6fc29b5f14eb), any one could help me?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an oustanding issue, but two workarounds I found so far:

1) Requiring a change in App.config.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/ab2a08d5-2e91-4dc1-bd80-6fc29b5f14eb

2) Indicating to rebuild service reference with svcutil instead of using Add Service Reference:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepointexcel/thread/2fd36e6b-5fa7-47a4-9d79-b11493d18107